# Cannot ssh to computer behind a router

Tags: networking, server, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a desktop at home that connects to a router, I had set up ssh port forwarding, allowed firewall access on the corresponding port and changed ssh config to listen to the specific port. It was all working correctly, I could ssh to my desktop remotely (from workplace). But recently we switched our internet provider, so brand new router etc, I went on to do all the same thing I had done before, but now seems like I cannot access to my desktop from remote computers (even with a laptop on the same local wireless network).

So both on the remote computer or a laptop in the same local wireless network, I would get the `Connection timed out` error, and if I ping my router's public ip adress, it shows 0 received: `50 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 50032ms`. Site like CanYouSeeMe.org shows that it can see my port.

Any suggestions? Thanks

*Edit:*

So from the related post below, someone suggested that

> Some ISPs use a system called CG-NAT to use one IP address for multiple connections, due to the global shortage of IPv4 addresses. This would prevent any incoming connections, and is typically used only on entry-level plans.

I wonder could this be true? How could this prevent any incoming connections, for example, the browser is sending request outward and getting result back all the time.

There is a related issue [Bell Home Hub 2000 Port Forwarding](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2720429/bell-home-hub-2000-port-forwarding.html#17270204.).

**Update**:

As suggested by davidbaumann in the comment section, I tried to access to the host on an external network just to make sure (I tried a while ago and it didn't work, so I have been testing access just from my local network), and it logged it, even though `ssh username@host_public_ip_adress -p external_port` still does not work in a local network, can someone explain?

Comment: when I ssh from a local laptop, I put down the router's public address. I changed the port to something else other than the default 22, which was recommended as a safe measure.

Comment: @dsstorefile Since you mentioned, so I tried `ssh username@host_local_ip_adress -p internal_port` and it worked

Comment: When using another port is recommended, it is usually the "public" port that changes.  So we have multiple devices behind NAT on 22, but a different public port for each? It does not hurt to change the private ports though.

Comment: @mckenzm The private port you mean is the internal port right? public  port as the external port. If so, I also had changed the internal port to non default.

Comment: That is also ok, and sometimes prudent.

Comment: If you fordward your external ip via router, for some model it works from internal network, and for some it doesn't. Did you try to connect from external network or your mobile phone for example?

Comment: Yeah I tried to access to it from an external network

Comment: @davidbaumann Hmm, I have tried ssh from an external network a while ago, but I tried again this morning from my work computer and it logged in, can you explain this as an answer to why some model doesn't work for the local network (if forward external ip via router)?